# Only show number bigger than zero with Angular

Tags: angularjs, conditional-statements

I dont want to show the price if it's value is 0, only show the name and nothing in price then !
If its greater than 0 then it should show both name and price.

How to do that?

```
<tr>
 <td>{{cars.name}}</td>
 <td>{{cars.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<tr>
 <td> {{cars.name}} </td>
 <td><div ng-show="cars.price > 0"> {{cars.price}} </div></td>
</tr>
```

**Edit:** if `ng-show` is evaluated to false it will hide the element by applying `display:none;` to the element style.

you can also use `ng-if` which will not render the element at all

Comment: -1 this answer without any description is not good for future users.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-if` if you don't want the cell included in the DOM, use `ng-show` if you want it to be included but not visible.

```
<tr>
 <td>{{cars.name}}</td>
 <td  ng-if="cars.price > 0">{{cars.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

If you're worried about HTML validators

```
<tr>
 <td>{{cars.name}}</td>
 <td ng-if="cars.price &gt; 0">{{cars.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

also works.

This will however probably skew your table a bit, since `ng-show` still uses `display:none;`. You can fix that by overriding the `.ng-hide` CSS class that gets assigned to hidden elements and set it to `visibility: hidden;` instead.